# rails - how to grab fixture data from within tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

I've looked at the [rails guide to testing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html) but I can seem to get fixture data from inside my test.  I have a fixture:

```
one:
  pay_period: one
  employee: kent
  cpp: 50
  ei: 40
  tax: 100
  vacation_pay: 30
```

Then I have a test as per below (where EmployeePayPeriod is a model)

```
require 'test_helper'
class EmployeePayPeriodTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  # Replace this with your real tests.
  test "Calculate wages under 80 hours correctly" do
    p = EmployeePayPeriod(:one)
    assert true
  end
end
```

Obviously the above isn't working.  I've looked at the guide.  In the guide it uses a code snippet to illustrate how you get fixture data:

```
@user = users(:david).
```

It seems that 'users' isn't a model (because the normal convention is that it would singular and capitalized. So where does 'users' come from?  If its autogenerated should there be a comparable 'employee_pay_periods' object available for me?  (I've tried, but it doesn't seem to work).

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe users is a convention based on the yml filename. In the example, they have a `users.yml`. So, to answer your question more directly, try whatever the name of your .yml fixture file is.

Something that might be easier in the long run, though, is something like [FactoryGirl](http://www.thoughtbot.com/projects/factory_girl), [Machinist](http://github.com/notahat/machinist), or [fixjour](http://github.com/nakajima/fixjour)

Comment: My pleasure. Good luck with the fixture'ing.

Answer (score 6):

The fixture needs to be in a .yml file whose name matches the table name (not the model name).

Assuming the table name for `EmployeePayPeriod` is `employee_pay_periods`, then your fixture needs to be in `test/fixtures/employee_pay_periods.yml`, and you should have an `employee_pay_periods()` method autogenerated for accessing the fixtures.

Make sure your fixtures are actually being loaded. Latest Rails will add the following line to test/test_helper.rb:

```
fixtures :all
```

This loads all fixtures before each test case. Make sure this line is there and not commented out.